# SQL Server Self Join is (unwanted) duplicating values in shorter columns to make all columns the same length

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table `MyTable` like the following:

```
column1 column2 column3
-----------------------
A       1       10
A       1       11
A       2       12
B       1       13
```

I want to get the following result:

```
output_column1 output_column2
-----------------------------
21             12
```

output_column1 is the sum of everything where column1=A and column2=1

output_column2 is the sum of everything where column1=A and column2=2

This is the code I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(tempNameA.column3) AS output_column1, 
    SUM(tempNameB.column3) AS output_column2
FROM 
    myTable tempNameA, myTable tempNameB
WHERE 
    tempNameA.column1 = 'A' 
    AND tempNameA.column2 = '1' 
    AND tempNameB.column1 = 'A' 
    AND tempNameB.column2 = '2'
```

However, because there are 2 values where column2=1 and only 1 value where column2=2, it is duplicating the value in column2 to make it have the same number of values as column1 and then giving me the following result, which is not what I want.  It should be 21 and 12, not 21 and 24

```
output_column1 output_column2
------------------------------
21             24
```

If I don't do sum, it shows the following:

```
output_column1 output_column2
------------------------------
10             12
11             12
```

But, I would expect this instead:

```
output_column1 output_column2
------------------------------------
10             12
11             0/blank/null/not 12
```

I'm sure this is an easy thing, but I haven't wrapped my head around it yet.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case when` with aggregate function `sum`

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.column1 = 'A' AND A.column2 = 1 THEN A.column3 ELSE 0 END) AS output_column1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.column1 = 'A' AND A.column2 = 2 THEN A.column3 ELSE 0 END) AS output_column2
FROM 
    myTable A
```

Result:

```
output_column1  output_column2
------------------------------
   21                  12
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/163df/1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand corrcly, you can use `CASE WHEN` and `SUM`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  column1 VARCHAR(6),
  column2 INT,
  column3 INT
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('A',1,10);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('A',1,11);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('A',2,12);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('B',1,13);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = 1 THEN column3 end) output_column1 ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN column2 = 2 THEN column3 end) output_column2
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM T 
  WHERE column1 ='A'
) t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5df57/4/0)**:

```
| output_column1 | output_column2 |
|----------------|----------------|
|             21 |             12 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to write this is:

```
select sum(case when t.column2 = 1 then t.column3 else 0 end) as output_column1,
       sum(case when t.column2 = 2 then t.column3 else 0 end) as output_column2
from myTable t
where t.column1 = 'A';
```

That is, put the common conditions in the `where` clause and the specific conditions in the conditional aggregation.